# Get IP and execute on IF statement

Tags: java

I can't process with my code.
I want to start my application if local Internet Protocol is equal to "XXX"
What i have wrote already wrote
Code:

```
InetAddress IP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println("SYSTEM IP = "+IP.getHostAddress());
```

Console :

```
SYSTEM IP= 192.168.0.69
```

How can i check: if my Internet Protocol is equal to 192.168.0.69 (or any i will get on other PC)
code executes;
else:
stops?

Thanks for advice if any!

Comment: This is just an easy and basic IF ELSE statement, with string comparison as condition statement. I don't think this is a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(IP.getHostAddress().equals("192.168.0.69")){
//code executes
}else{
// stops
}
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Easy and simple string. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[`getHostAddress`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress%28%29) returns a `String`:

```
public String getHostAddress()
       ↑
```

---

So simply do:

```
if("192.168.0.69".equals(IP.getHostAddress())) {
    //...
}
```

It's preferable not to use *magic strings*, so make it `static final String`..

Answer (score 0):

```
if(IP != null && IP.getHostAddress().equals("192.168.0.69"))
{
 System.out.println("The address is matched");
}

IP.getHostAddress() method return the value in `String` so you can check the IP address using `equals` method.
```